# python and SQLite library

Tags: python, sqlite

I am just starting to work with python and databases.

After importing the sqlite3 library I queried dir(sqlite3) to have a look at the methods available in this library, but I cannot seem to get the syntax right to do a 'help' query so I can learn more about them.

E.g. I tried to query help for 'Connection', 'Cursor', 'SQLITE_CREATE_TABLE', as a few examples.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What about `help(sqlite3)`?

Comment: Just read the [fine manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).